# Can't find npm module 'meteor-deque'

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

I am trying to deploy my meteor app on Modulus but I am getting these errors on the console

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor-deque'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'meteor' package?
at Object.Npm.require (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:175:17)
at Meteor.startup (packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:17:1)
at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:816:4
at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1274:3
at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:137:5

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/mnt/app/.modulus/nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start script 'node ../../main'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ../../main
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My node version is 0.10.4
My meteor version is 1.2.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use Node 0.10.40 with Meteor 1.2+ (Node 0.10.36 for 1.0+)

Comment: That is correct, there is a bug in the 0.12.* versions of Node which doesn't play well with Meteor

Comment: How do I specify which version to be used with my meteor project?

Comment: I have tested what version of node is being used on modulus and that is 0.10.40

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution to it eventually?

Comment: @Naor I just uninstalled it, removed and deployed it again and then it worked. Wasn't able to find out the deal issue.

Comment: Thanks. My way around it was to install a newer version of node (on my machine). It's possible that this happened since I was switching nodejs versions for some projects with nvm, and might installed Modulus CLI with a version that was incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

please upgrade to Meteor 1.4.2.3 (latest) and install the babel-runtime NPM (as Meteor 1.4.2.1 no longer provides its own babel functions):

```
cd /your/app/directory
meteor update
meteor npm install babel-runtime --save
meteor
```

If you still have problems, try a Meteor reset:

```
meteor reset
```

## If you *still* have problems, please reinstall Meteor:

Reinstalling Meteor from meteor.com
  cd to my app directory

```
meteor rebuild
meteor reset
```

Reinstall any packages you've added
Run the app

```
meteor
```

Comment: Surprisingly `meteor reset` (note: this deletes dev db!) on local project and then `mup deploy` helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I built the bundle without specifying the target architecture I am deploying it for. I was using a windows OS to create the bundle for a linux deployment server. 
As an example, if you are targeting a linux deployment server, then use the following

meteor build --directory build --server-only --architecture os.linux.x86_64